# How to cast double or double array into double array always in C#

Tags: c#, casting

I have method which process the double arrays. I am supplying double arrays using keyword `params`. My problem is sometimesI have to pass doubles as well and I want to use to same method for both types. Currently method have signature

```
public void DoSomething(params double[][] arrays)
```

Above method definition works fine for following arguments:

```
double [] array = new double []{2,3,5} ;
double [] anotherarray = new double []{7,8,10} ;
DoSomething (array, anotherarray) ;
```

I am thing to pass object and then cast them in this method and use try catch block and I do not know it is right approach or there exists some elegant way to handle this kind of situation because I can have mixed data as input arguments.

```
public void DoSomething(params object objs)
{   
   // for loop
   try 
   {
      var tempdata =  (double) objs(loop index);
      double[] data = new double[] { tempdata };
   } 
   catch 
   {
      var tempdata = (double []) objs(loop index);
      double [] data = tempdata;
   }
   // do other opertaion
}
```

I want to call this way:

```
double [] array = new double []{2,3,5} ;
double singlevalue = 10 ;
double [] anotherarray = new double []{7,8,10} ;
DoSomething (array, singlevalue, anotherarray) ;
```

Comment: Why don't you just overload the method?

Comment: I mentioned that my data can be mixed type and due to which I am looking this kind of functionality

Comment: @JonSkeet: if it does the same thing for say doubles and singles wouldn't you need to at some point call a common overload or either repeat all the code? (apologies if I am being slow on a friday morning here).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "mixed data" here? It doesn't help that you haven't shown any examples of *calling* the method. If you sometimes have `double[][]` and sometimes have `double[]`, but those are the only options, then I would definitely suggest adding an overload (and making one overload call the other).

Comment: @Chris: I haven't seen any indication that `float` is required yet - the OP isn't being very specific, but I can only see `double[]` and `duoble[][]` at the moment, which can definitely be handled with overloads. And yes, one overload would call the other, but that's fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Ah, I think I saw casting and assumed it was casting the double part. Not arrays into different arrays...

Comment: Now I understand better any reason not to just force the caller to put things into arrays?

Comment: Actually, I am working with a method to save data in text file while debugging and open in excel or some other tool at same time to analyze it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you've given an example of how you want to call it, I suspect that using dynamic typing may be the simplest approach:

```
public void DoSomething(params object[] values)
{
    foreach (dynamic value in values)
    {
        // Overload resolution will be performed at execution time
        DoSomethingImpl(value);
    }
}

private void DoSomethingImpl(double value) { ... }

private void DoSomethingImpl(double[] value) { ... }
```

You could do it manually if you want:

```
public void DoSomething(params object[] values)
{
    foreach (object value in values)
    {
        if (value is double)
        {
            DoSomethingImpl((double) value);
            // Or: DoSomethingImpl(new[] { (double) value });
        }
        else if (value is double[])
        {
            DoSomethingImpl((double[]) value);
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

I would definitely *not* just cast unconditionally and then catch the exception that's thrown. That's a horrible abuse of exceptions.

Comment: yes, I was not feeling comfortable with try catch block.I thought may be I could save few lines of code and however it seems difficult. Thanks for help.